Website behaves differently during Selenium automation compared to manual browsing
I am trying to automate a task using selenium, the issue I am facing is on this link, when you press the button Vote for Asteria MU SEASON 20 PART 1-2 - 99999x and then you will be redirected to a new page where you have to enter a simple captcha, and when you enter it incorrect and even sometimes when you enter correct it shows that it is wrong but when I am doing it using selenium even if I enter a wrong captcha text it does not show me that it is incorrect can someone explain me???

from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


def move_to_voting_page(driver, URL):
    driver.get(URL)
    input_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Vote for Asteria MU SEASON 20 PART 1-2 - 99999x']")
    input_element.click()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    return driver
    

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    URL = "https://www.xtremetop100.com/sitedetails-1132227942"
    driver = move_to_voting_page(driver, URL)
    
    sleep(1000)
    driver.quit()

now as you can see I am not doing anything all I am doing is going to the captcha page now even after going to that page and after that even if I enter everything manually I do not see anything after entering the captcha like even if I enter in the wrong captcha then too I see a white screen and nothing else, can someone explain me what is happening???

captchas usually have some bot-detection built-in.

I dont think that is causing the problem in this case bcz i tried simply to open the base URL and after that I manually went to the page having the captcha and entered it manually but still I am getting the same error

if you used Selenium to launch the browser it will launch in dev-mode (with wire protocol)

Ohh, is there a way to disable this wire mode, or is it possible to prevent a website to know that the browser sending the request is from an automated task??

@VardanVerma Try undetected chromedriver https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver
